# npm cannot find material-ui module even though it is correctly installed

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui

I installed the package following the instructions on the material-ui website:

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

And verified the module is correctly installed using `npm ls`

```
npm ls
pwiki-frontend@0.1.0 /home/gilles/web-dev/pwiki-frontend
├── ...
├── @emotion/styled@11.10.5
├── @mui/material@5.11.4
├── @mui/styled-engine-sc@5.11.0
├── ...
```

I include the components I want to use from the module in `index.js` as follows (from [their demo](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tree-view/)):

```
import TreeView from '@mui/lab/TreeView';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore';
import ChevronRightIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ChevronRight';
import TreeItem from '@mui/lab/TreeItem';
```

When I start the development server with `npm start` I get the following output:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/lab/TreeView' in '/path/to/root-dir/src'
ERROR in ./src/index.js 11:0-41
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/lab/TreeView' in '/path/to/root-dir/src'

ERROR in ./src/index.js 12:0-60
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore' in '/path/to/root-dir/src'

ERROR in ./src/index.js 13:0-64
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/icons-material/ChevronRight' in '/path/to/root-dir/src'

ERROR in ./src/index.js 14:0-41
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/lab/TreeItem' in '/path/to/root-dir/src'
```

I have tried export `NODE_PATH` using the relative path as well as the global path, but neither worked.

```
export NODE_PATH=./node_modules
export NODE_PATH=/path/to/root_dir/node_modules
```

What am I doing wrong?

I thought that a simple 'npm install` should be enough to get everything working correctly.
I tried a different module before material-ui and I was having the same issue with that module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the TreeView component from the **@mui/lab** dependency, which has components that are not yet ready to be part of the main **@mui/material** dependency as you can see [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/about-the-lab/).

To fix that, add the dependency to your `package.json` running `npm install @mui/lab`.

The same is happening to the icons that you are trying to use, you'll need to add the `@mui/icons-material` to use them.